# Is overflow_error caught at runtime in C++ when a integer variable cannot hold a value that it is not supposed to

Tags: c++

I am learning C++, I was trying to write this function to find the largest fibonacci integer that can fit into an integer type:

```
void findFibThatFitsInAnInt()
{
    int n1 = 1;
    int n2 = 1;
    int fib = 0;
    try
    {
        while ( true )
        {
            fib = n1 + n2;
            n1 = n2;
            n2 = fib;
            cout << "Fibonacci number : " << fib << "\n";
        } 

    }
    catch (overflow_error & e)
    {
        cout << "The largest fib that can fit into an int is : " << fib << "\n";
        cout << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    cout << "The largest fib that can fit into an int is : " << n1 << "\n";
}
```

But the thing is overflow_error is not caught at all. 
I know other ways of doing this:

I know that I can write like :

```
while ( fib >= 0 )
        {
            fib = n1 + n2;
            n1 = n2;
            n2 = fib;
            cout << "Fibonacci number : " << fib << "\n";
        }
```

and because fib is just an "int" not an unsigned int, it will eventually become < 0 ( strangely enough ) when it is assigned a value that is larger than the capacity of int type.

Question is : is overflow_error for this kind of capacity issue caught at runtime in C++? Did I misunderstand something about overflow_error? This is what I know from my google foo:

> Defines a type of object to be thrown as exception. It can be used to
>   report arithmetic overflow errors (that is, situations where a result
>   of a computation is too large for the destination type)

If overflow_error is ignored for integer overflows is there a way to enable it for my c++ compiler ( visual studio 2013?)

Comment: Why do you think `std::overflow_error` or _any_ exception for that matter will be thrown here?

Comment: won't it catch overflow_error if the int fib is assigned a very large value?

Comment: see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/overflow_error): The only standard library components that throw this exception are std::bitset::to_ulong and std::bitset::to_ullong.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: The phrase _"can be used to report"_ does not indicate that it _is_ used or that it _is_ thrown automatically for integers.

Comment: To really push @AlexD's answer, signed integer overflow is **undefined behavior** ( http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html ).  Other languages handle this differently.  What you want is probably something like SafeInt ( https://safeint.codeplex.com/ ), or doing the same checks by hand.

Comment: For `gcc`, passing the flag `-ftrapv` will catch integer overflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: No.  Neither C nor C++ will automatically detect integer overflow at runtime.

Here are more details about C++ std::overflow_error:

> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/overflow_error
>
> `std::overflow_error`   Defined in header `<stdexcept>`
>
> Defines a type of object to be thrown as exception. It can be used to
>   report arithmetic overflow errors (that is, situations where a result
>   of a computation is too large for the destination type)
>
> The only standard library components that throw this exception are
>   std::bitset::to_ulong and std::bitset::to_ullong.
>
> The mathematical functions of the standard library components do not
>   throw this exception (mathematical functions report overflow errors as
>   specified in math_errhandling). Third-party libraries, however, use
>   this. For example, boost.math throws std::overflow_error if
>   boost::math::policies::throw_on_error is enabled (the default
>   setting).

Here is more information about what you can do in your code to detect and handle integer overflow:

[How to detect integer overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

Comment: Ok. can you tell me what is the use of bitset types  and where they are used? Is there a way to enable overflow_error for integer overflow?

Comment: @svasa There is no switch nor c++ library that enables exceptions for integer owerflows. They are silent by design.

Comment: You can enable integer overflow checking in MSVS by using a [checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) block: http://rion.io/2013/04/27/enabling-underflow-and-overflow-checking-within-visual-studio/.  Unfortunately, this is Microsoft-specific :(  You can also use [Boost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), and specify `boost::math::policies::throw_on_error`.

Comment: Hmm, ok. So programmer needs to carefully write his code avoiding overflows , because they are not caught !

Comment: Yes.  C was always like that, and C++ followed.  Here is a good discussion: [Integer Overflow is a Menace](https://benjamin.pe/writing/integer-overflow)

Comment: Marking this as answer for the link where it shows how to enable the overflow detection in VS

Answer (score 7):

According to the standard (emphasis mine):

> **5 Expressions [expr]**
> ....
>
> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of
> representable values for its type, ***the behavior is undefined***. [ *Note*: ***most existing implementations of C++
> ignore integer overflows***.

P.S. BTW, please note that

> **3.9.1 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]**
> ....
>
> (*footnote*)
> ***unsigned arithmetic does not overflow*** because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting
> unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the
> resulting unsigned integer type.

Comment: Note that undefined behavior allows throwing `std::overflow_error`, so a conforming implementation *may* throw that exception. As everyone else already stated, no implementation does.

Comment: Note that undefined behavior also allows "turn a terminating loop into an infinite loop," or "eliding an unrelated `NULL`-check," or "generating an executable that does things that the language standard wouldn't normally allow."  And that some implementations do, in fact, take advantage of that definition ( http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html ).

Answer (score 4):

> is overflow_error for this kind of capacity issue caught at runtime in C++?

No, as from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/overflow_error)

> > The only standard library components that throw this exception are `std::bitset::to_ulong` and `std::bitset::to_ullong`.

Overflows as induced by intrinsic mathematical operations won't be caught, and just leave you with unexpected results. The exact behavior isn't defined in the standard ([great cite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35138909/1413395) in [@AlexD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3246555/alexd)
's answer).