# How to generate overflow_error or underflow_error exception in c++?

Tags: c++, exception

I want to check under what circumstance will overflow_error and underflow_error exception be generated in c++, so I wrote a demo to try to generate overflow_error exception, but failed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using std::cout; using std::endl;
int main() {
    try {
        int a = std::pow(2, 31) - 1;
        cout << a << endl;
        int b = 1;
        int c = a + b;
        cout << c << endl;
    } catch (std::overflow_error ex) {
        cout << ex.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The out put is:

```
2147483647
-2147483648
```

As you can see, no overflow_error exception generated, so, my questions are what the arithmetic overflow errors and arithmetic underflow errors are and how to generate overflow_error and underflow_error exception in c++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is overflow\_error caught at runtime in C++ when a integer variable cannot hold a value that it is not supposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138864/is-overflow-error-caught-at-runtime-in-c-when-a-integer-variable-cannot-hold-a)

Comment: Which unfortunately didn't cover the `underflow_error`.

Comment: Why don't you post an answer so that I can mark it favorite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only standard library components that throw `std::overflow_error` are `std::bitset::to_ulong` and `std::bitset::to_ullong`.

The standard library components do not throw `std::underflow_error` (mathematical functions report underflow errors as specified in math_errhandling).

In your example, you are trying to check signed integer overflow. 
You need to specify flag for this check.

For example:

Use `clang++` to compile and link your program with `-fsanitize=undefined` flag.

```
% cat test.cc
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int k = 0x7fffffff;
  k += argc;
  return 0;
}
% clang++ -fsanitize=undefined test.cc
% ./a.out
```

test.cc:3:5: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483647 + 1 cannot be represented in type 'int'

Comment: Note that the flag is compiler-specific.